# Связь функций абзаца с принадлежностью текста

Tags: стилистика, оформление-текста

Как Вы понимаете высказывание Валгиной?

Очень часто в разных ответах звучит сочувствие детям, сдающим ЕГЭ. На сегодняшний день ЕГЭ по русскому языку особых трудностей, на мой взгляд, не вызывает. По крайней мере, на тройку сдаст любой, кто ответит на 17 вопросов из 30 части А, а еще ведь есть и В, и С... А вот девятиклассникам стоит посочувствовать, так как, ответив на ВСЕ вопросы тестовой части, они тройку не получают. Надо еще написать на слух сжатое изложение (слушают аудиозапись, чтение быстрое), а в этом году вместо привычного и понятного сочинения по тексту предлагается написать рассуждение на лингвистическую тему по цитате. (Раскрыть смысл цитаты, привести два примера из текста). Набор цитат не ограничен. Есть примерный перечень. Вот одна из них. Очень прошу Вас ответить, как Вы понимаете данное высказывание.

«Функции абзаца тесно связаны с функционально-стилевой принадлежностью текста, вместе с тем отражают и индивидуально-авторскую особенность оформления текста». 
Нина Сергеевна Валгина

Я вот так, навскидку, без специального изучения, не могу сказать, как зависит абзацное членение от стиля речи. И что считать нарушением абзацного членения, а что авторской особенностью? А Вы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу точно сказать, что в научных текстах абзацы гораздо длиннее. Трудно, конечно,
сравнивать вообще, ибо никогда нет требуемого при таких сравнениях "при прочих равных",
но,   думаю, у меня - раза в 2-3.

Ошибки... Ну вот, например, явная ошибка выносить в отдельный абзац "высказывание" Валгиной, которое можно уяснить только в контексте. 
Ни в ["Теории текста"](http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/valgina.teoriya_teksta.moskva.logos.2003p173_(sl).htm), ни в ["Актуальных проблемах современной русской пунктуации"](http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/valgina.aktualnuye_ptobl_rus_punkt.2004.259_(sl).htm)
такого нет, а в синтаксисе ["Современного русского языка"](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-056.htm) цитата абзац выглядит так:

*Функции абзаца в диалогической и монологической речи различны: в диалоге абзац служит 
для разграничения реплик разных лиц, т.е. выполняет чисто формальную роль; в монологической 
речи - для выделения композиционно значимых частей текста (как с точки зрения логико-
смысловой, так и эмоционально-экспрессивной). Функции абзаца тесно связаны с функционально-
стилевой принадлежностью текста и его стилистической окрашенностью, вместе с тем отражают и 
индивидуально-авторскую особенность оформления текста. В частности, средний объем абзацев 
часто зависит от манеры письма.*

Здесь, помимо восстановленной купюры при цитировании (что само по себе уже большое "фе" 
дядям, готовившим этот материал), с первой же фразы понятно, о каких функциях абзаца идёт 
речь (разграничение реплик разных лиц и выделение композиционно значимых частей текста).
Всё, чего ещё огород городить?

В отношении ЕГЭ. Ваше мнение мне было интересно, поскольку ранее хоть сколько-нибудь 
положительных отзывов от профессионалов о ЕГЭ не читал. Если интересно, посмотрите на 
грамоте постоянные "критические жалобы" (не знаю, как назвать) на грамоте. Сам форум там 
правда сейчас представляет довольно странное зрелище, но "фильтруя базар" можно найти много 
ценного.

Comment: Спасибо большое! И как я не догадалась поискать текст целиком? Все бы ничего, если не брать во внимание, что вопрос этот для обычных девятиклассников. В прошлом году их весь год на одну цитату буквально "натаскивали", а в этот году, по сути, "кот в мешке"

Моя ошибка в абзацном членении была целенаправленной: цитата должна была быть легко видимой, легко вычленяемой. Это и есть авторская особенность членения текста. Жду ответов и других коллег.

Comment: Что касается размера абзаца: у Толстого размер предложения может быть страницы полторы... (как раз его индивидуальная особенность)). За часть цитаты про диалогическую - монологическую речь особое спасибо, действительно, диалог чаще всего - принадлежность разговорного стиля или стиля художественной литературы, если она этот разговор передает.  А у детей обычно тексты как раз художественного стиля с диалогами...

Comment: Про ЕГЭ. Спасибо, конечно, но читать мнения некомпетентных людей или учеников (настоящих или в недавнем прошлом)ленивых, не желающих учебник прочитать внимательно, не хочется. Потому что, еще раз повторю, сдать ЕГЭ на тройку легко. А набрать 80-100 баллов - это, конечно, трудно и зависит не только от подготовки в последний год перед экзаменом, но и от общей культуры ученика и его семьи.

Comment: >Моя ошибка в абзацном членении была целенаправленной

Я имел в виду выдергивание цитаты из контекста. Оформленная как законченный абзац она неизбезно вызывает недоумение. Вы тут не ошиблись, это я про составителей вопросов.

>но читать мнения *некомпетентных* людей   

Ну-ну... 

*Кот подпрыгнул на стуле от обиды.  
- Помилуйте, королева, - прохрипел он, - разве  я  позволил  бы  себе
налить даме водки? Это чистый спирт!* (МАБ)

Впрочем, не смею настаивать.

Comment: Я хотела сказать только  то, что сказала. На тройку сдать легко. Если это опровергают, значит "не в теме".

Comment: > На тройку сдать легко.  

Согласна. Я проверила сына, в части А сделал более половины. А ведь он перешел только в 6 класс! Не смог ответить в основном те вопросы, где нужно знать терминологию. Ну, это дело наживное.

Comment: А если опровергают не это?
Ларf, среди "опровергающих" (якобы) есть человек, выезжавший на точки с методическими проверками. И разговор был, "в теме" ли те, кто ЕГЭ составляет, а не сдает или принимает.

ЗЯ и далась вам это тройка... Отличники, готовящиеся на филфак, срезаются. Вот что страшно. Ладно, замнём.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна, что сочинение на лингвистическую тему - не то, о чём хотели бы думать и писать девятиклассники. 
Фраза Н.С.Валгиной вырвана из контекста и являет собой непростую задачу не только для пятнадцатилетних школьников. 
Что считать нарушением членения? В тексте есть микротемы, "работающие" на идею, они должны быть выделены. Если микротемы сливаются, сдваиваются, это нарушение членения. Если дробится одна микротема, это тоже нарушение членения.
А вот индивидуально-авторское оформление текста (сочинения)- это большой риск для ученика, который автором сам (при написании сочинения) является. Ибо учитель не всегда угадывает оригинальный замысел ученика и безжалостно ставит  на полях тетради помету, указывающую на нарушение абзацного членения. Да ещё и снижает оценку.
По поводу ГИА по русскому языку в 9 классе. Мне понравилось, что ввели аудиозапись, это помогает детям сжимать текст. Способ "исключение" при сжатии они точно используют).